# How to configure logging in python with different modules writing to the same destination

Tags: python, logging

So... I've read [this](http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python) and all the logging tutorials (maybe I've missed something)

Let's say I have two packages with two classes.

package Foo
class Foo

package Bar
class Bar

And class Foo is using class Bar.

And class Bar is using external library.

What I wan't is to be able configure logging in such way that I would see the logs of Bar and Foo in one file, but not the logs from external library. And I would wan't to do that without code duplication.

I already know how to write logs to file and how to configure logging from file (json, yaml). But I don't want to write the same lines of configure code in every file.

Maybe there is some 'right' way to do it, that I'm missing?

EDIT1

Oh, and I forgot to say, that this packages are installed with setup.py and Bar is used by some other projects also.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write lines to configure logging in each file - just in one place called from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. You can configure loggers for `Foo` and `Bar` to use the same `FileHandler`, and you can use an appropriate level (or `Filter`) for the external library logger which will prevent any logging from the external library from being output. AFAIK you can do this without code duplication using the approaches that are documented.

If you try something according to what I've said and run into specific problems, you can update your question to be more specific and hopefully get a more specific answer.

**Update:** For more information on `__name__ == '__main__'`, see [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

Comment: Where is this 'if __name__ == '__main__' should be?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my question was not clear enough. I know exactly what this line of code do. But WHERE should I put it (in Foo, in Bar or in other project that is using them)? Can you give simple example of setting logging with Foo and Bar?